# Cómo hacer un backup de una base de datos postgres en windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql

#### Actualizado

Al parecer sólo se debe hacer
`pg_dump -U <usuario> <nombre_bd>`

Entro de 2 formas y me sale el mismo error:

1. entro por `Inicio- Todos los programas - PostgreSQL 9.4 - SQL Shell` y coloco esa instrucción y no pasa nada, si le pongo al final `;` me dice que hay un error de sintaxis.
2. entro por `cmd - cd C:\Files Program\Postgresql\9.4\bin` y coloco la misma instrucción... sin ; no pasa nada y con ; sale error de sintaxis.

Me pueden colaborar? yo no sé usar windows para estas cosas y algunas otras ya se me han olvidado. Si es posible me gustaría que el backup quedara en el escritorio o en mis Documentos.

Comment: debes hacerlo desde la linea de comandos de windows (`cmd`), no desde la shell de postgres.

Comment: Diana podrías escribir exactamente como estas escribiendo la instrucción?, estas reemplazando los valores entre "< >" verdad, debería funcionar sin problema también podrías agregar al final la instrucción " -f miarchivodump.sql"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como lo dice @rnd, esos comandos se deben correr en la consola de comandos de Windows, precisamente en el enlace que pones, la persona pregunta cómo hacerlo desde la consola de comandos.

La consola de comandos en Windows la abres simplemente oprimiendo <kbd>tecla windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, escribes `cmd` y luego la ejecutas desde ahí. También la puedes abrir desde el menú de inicio y buscas cmd.

Para que tengas mayor idea del comando puedes ver este [enlace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/app-pgdump.html).

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez si perdió la contraseña sería mejor resetear la contraseña del usuario de `Postgres`. Aquí hay una [pregunta de stackoverflow en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845998/i-forgot-the-password-i-entered-during-postgres-installation) que te puede ayudar aunque no sé si entienes inglés :S.

Answer (score 4):

Para realizar un backup en la vs 9.5 de postgres en windows:

- Entra a la consola de windows
- Dirigete a la ruta donde se encuentra alojado el archivo con el comando cd. Por defecto es `C:\Archivos de programas\postgresql\9.5\bin`
- Ejecuta la siguiente línea:

  ```
  pg_dump.exe -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -v -d 
  {nombre_de_tu_db} -f {ruta_donde_se_aloja_el_archivo}
  ```

La ruta puede ser algo como `C:\xampp\htdocs\carpeta_proyecto\pyFecha.backup`

PD: recuerda colocarle la extensión '.**backup**' a tu archivo

Answer (score 2):

Ingresas desde cmd a la ruta donde tienes la instalación de postgresql 
ejecutas el siguiente comando.

```
pg_dump.exe -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -v -d NOMBRE_BD -f RUTA
```

Te dejo este link para que puedas ver el proceso.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ4pRSRPfWk#action=share